# Map and unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11

My question is more for learning purpose than for debugging purpose:

I'm currently optimising a code for a little game of mine, and I wanted to know:

I'm using a map for dispatching some value inside my programme, so is a unordered_map faster in use than a map?

(btw sorry for my english, it's not my native language!)

Comment: Why don't you measure it?

Comment: because i wanted to know if there's a good way to use it and if the performance change is large before changing a big part of my code!

Comment: The main thing to learn is that you have to measure these things in a realistic running scenario.

Comment: Another important thing to learn is to write code in a way that makes it easy to switch between the two containers, so it becomes easy to measure the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here is that a `map` internally uses a [red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) and a unordered map is s [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The `unordermap` is very fast compared to the `map` because putting elements into the map required just 1 (O(1)) "actions" where the map needs to find the correct position in the tree to store the value which was put into the map (O(log n)). You can also read the C++ doc for [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) and [unordermap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/)

Comment: So if i understand clearly: map is faster in search but unorderd_map is faster in modification?

Comment: search, insert and delete is O(1) for the unordered map and the same operations for the map are O(log(n)), which makes the unordered map faster for all operations. The main advantage of the map is that all keys can be traveresed in an ordered way wihtout any effort, because they are already ordered internally. Use the unordered map for performance and the map only if you need you key in an ordered way

Comment: Think of an priority queue for tasks. Every task has a priority, let's say you reveive new tasks in an unorder way, you just put them into your map and afterwars you can process them ordered by their priority becuase the map ordered them. For the unordered map you first need to retrived all tasks from the unorder map an order them depending on their priority.

Comment: Your answer was quite usefull thanks! after testing the unordered map is quite faster for my use! but is creating an hash function (third parameter of the tamplate) and obligatory task or can i ignore it?

Comment: Classes from the STL and built-in types will already have hash functions. You only need to supply one if you want to use a user-defined class as the key.

Comment: @TartanLlama thanks for your answer, do you know where i should search for an example of this case? (i'll search too but if you know some more useful site!)

Comment: Sure, have a read through [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/user-defined-hash-functions-for-unordere/231600210). That site is always good to look to if you want guidance on something C++ related.

Comment: You can't really say the `unordered_map` is faster than the `map`. Algorithmic complexity is not the same as speed. Speed depends on many things and you really have to measure it. For instance, inserting into an unordered_map could cause expensive copies, while inserting into a map wouldn't.

Comment: Extending the hashmap and re-hasing which can result from an insert is time consuming that's true. If you know the number of elements you want to insert in advance you can already initialize the hashmap with the proper value. In Java they advice you to choose the size 1.33 * number of elements (which is a loadfactor of 0.75) to avoid rehashing and stuff

Answer (score 2):

A `std::unordered_map` is a "hash_map", which means that searching it is O(1), where a `std::map` is a red-black tree, searching that is O(log2(n)). So, if you have 1000 elements, the difference is looking at 10 keys in the `std::map` before finding the "right" one, vs. looking at one. With 1 million elements, we look at 20 keys in the `std::map` before getting to the "right" one - still only one in a `std::unordered_map`.

However, you need to hash the "key", which means doing some form of calculation to make it a number.

It also depends on how often you insert/remove elements, compared to how often you just look up the elements.

For larger data-sets, the size and locality can also have a big impact, and searching through the "first few layers" is often quick because it's in the cache [if you are searching through the same map several times], where unordered map is taking up more space (have to have some "spare" slots, because it's very unlikely that all 10000 elements generate hash values that are exactly 10000 elements, so typically, the hash map is far from "full"). Because "recent" hash searches are unlikely to match current ones, cache probably doesn't help much either.

And of course, the `std::unordered_map` is, as the name implies, unordered - if you iterate through it, the keys are in hash-order (modulo bucket-count, so even if you know the hash, it's typically hard to know what order it is), not in "sorted" order. This can be important in some cases.

So whether that gives you any noticeable performance benefit is something you will have to figure out by measuring the performance.

Comment: Also, map requires less space so if  space is more important than speed then a map might be better.

Comment: Lots of half-truths in there, but it's too big a topic to do justice here so fair enough.  "unordered_map... keys are in hash-order" though - it's usually `% bucket_count` which is quite different.